# Why is this self-referential Generics assignment illegal?

Tags: java, generics

I am having a hard time understanding why the error below happens.  If #1 is ok, why is #2 not?

```
public interface IFoobar<DATA extends IFoobar> {
    void bigFun();
}

class FoobarImpl<DATA extends IFoobar> implements IFoobar<DATA> {
    public void bigFun() {
        DATA d = null;
        IFoobar<DATA> node = d;    //#1 ok
        d = node;                  //#2 error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `DATA` is a type of `IFoobar`, but not the other way around.  It's no different than:

```
String d = null;
Object o = d;                //#1 ok
d = o;                       //#2 error
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the compiler knows that the `DATA` type implements `IFoobar`. But it *doesn't* know that all `IFoobar` objects are actually `DATA` objects. Simply having `DATA` as a generic parameter doesn't mean anything; you could just as well implement another unrelated class that implements `IFoobar<DATA>`.